# How can I get the modified table name(any table in db) and it's modified value without using triggers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am creating database snapshot for reporting(creating a common demoralized table from normalized tables), for which I need to enter normalized tables modified values at the same time when the table modify. I want a common solution for this. Same is achievable using triggers but I am looking for some other generic solution which will work with any table change. Is there any other way in SQL server by which I can achieve the same?

Comment: This question is not related to SSIS or SSRS!!

Comment: Yes - CDC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server

Comment: Also replication.